# Error constructing a mongo export query

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, ubuntu-14.04, mongoexport

I keep getting error in constructing a query with paramters in bash script
Without any parameters, I am able to export records. But escaping of the special characters seems to be very hard.

```
    cname="CollectionName"
    dbname="DBName"
    startDate=2018-08-01
    endDate=2018-08-02
    sDate=$(date -d "$startDate" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ' )
    eDate=$(date -d "$endDate" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')
    query="'{"updatedTimestamp" : {$gte : ISODate('${sDate}'), $lt : ISODate('${midDate}')}}"
    mongoexport --host <hostname> --port <portname> --authenticationMechanism PLAIN --authenticationDatabase \$external --username <username>--password <password> --collection ${cname} --db ${dbname} --query ${query} --out out.json


./mongo_export_s3_upload.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./mongo_export_s3_upload.sh: line 26: `query=\'{"updatedTimestamp":{\"\$gte\": new Date(${sDate})}}\''
```

**Updated :** 
set -x helped a lot. One thing i learned is , dont rely on echo statements for debugging.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
 cname="CollectionName"
    dbname="DBName"
endDate="2018-08-02"
sDate=$(date -d "$startDate" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ' )
eDate=$(date -d "$endDate" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')
query='{"updatedTimestamp":{$gte:ISODate("'${sDate}'"),$lt:ISODate("'${eDate}'")}}'
mongoexport --host <hostname> --port <portname> --authenticationMechanism PLAIN  --authenticationDatabase \$external --username <username>--password <password>  --collection ${cname} --db ${dbname} -q ${query} --out out.json
```

Comment: SO won't allow me to directly suggest tiny edits : do you mean "eDate" instead of "midDate"?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, I find it easier to dictate the `$` expansion I want and don't want (and to read my script) if I break the string construction into several lines, like so:

```
query='{updatedTimestamp : {$gte : ISODate('
query=${query}${sDate}
query=${query}'), $lt : ISODate('
query=${query}${eDate}
query=${query}')}}'
```

If the MongoDB syntax needs `'` quotes around the dates, you can add lines like this, before and after the lines that concatenate the dates onto the string:

```
query=${query}"'"
```

or, do something like this:

```
query=${query}"'), \$lt : ISODate('"
```

Sometimes, I then re-combine the multiple lines into one line, once I see that the multi-line version is working;  IOW, breaking it up helps me see how it needs to be (re)written as one line.

Comment: i followed the same approach but getting the following error. 2018-07-26T16:29:33.358+0000 too many positional arguments: [: {$gte : ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt : ISODate("2018-08-02T00:00:00.000Z")}}']
2018-07-26T16:29:33.358+0000 try 'mongoexport --help' for more information. However if i echo the variable and execute the value of variable , mongoexport runs fine

Comment: @jojo : one thing that helps me is to `echo` the entire command that I want the script to execute; I then compare that to the command that I would run by hand; there is usually a tiny but crucial difference; to see the difference, I will sometimes go so far as to put the two versions of the command in a text file so I can compare them character-by-character, or in two separate files so I can run vimdiff and have vimdiff highlight the exact difference

Comment: i tried echo entire command and ran it seperately. It works fine. But the bash script throws error as follows                                                                                           too many positional arguments: [: {$gte : ISODate("2018-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt : ISODate("2018-08-02T00:00:00.000Z")}}']

Comment: @jojo : can you edit your question to add the updated bash script?  seeing the exact line(s) might help me see what's going wrong

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Provided the solution as an update to the original post

Comment: @jojo : I'm glad you worked it out;  was my answer enough of a help to warrant accepting it?  or at least up-voting it?